# Retopology, am I doing it right?

Tags: modeling

I've read somewhere that quads are used a lot in games. An as i sculpted my model it was triangulated by default. Then i used a tool (meshlab) to get a low poly model. I ended up with a 6.7k verts model but everything were tirangles. Since then i found out it's better to use quads and learned about retopology.I found a lot of images on google but I don't know if i'm doing it right. Some google models have very few polygons and some a lot more so i'm asking here. Here's an image of my retopology process so far:

[image]

It's only a part of the head and there are already 677 verts. My meshlab model had 6.7. So i think that i will end up with having more verts with retopology than with meshlab. So here's my question. Does this looks right to you or i'm doing something wrong?

Thanks

UPDATE Progress:

[image]

Comment: The mesh is a bit dense in parts of the nose(?). If this is for a game you should have some approximate target vert count in mind so that you don't exceed that and find out performance is laggy and have to re-retopo. I would go way more low-poly than that, and then SubDiv+Shrinkwrap it to the original sculpt. What you have is a good starting point. Try to Dissolve some of those edge loops. You can use Shrinkwrap and Multires in a way that you can create multiple versions of the mesh at different densities.

Comment: Also, Select All and Recalculate Normals (Ctrl N) once in a while. Half your face normals are flipped - that's why you have dark areas, and they will probably cause problems with Shrinkwrap if you leave them like that.

Comment: @Mentalist I don't really know how to fix this, The edges around nostrils are spitting to cover more face a bit further so i don't know what to do to get less polygones at the nostrils area. I also have the same problem with ears. Since i need quads i don''t know what to do to keep quads and less faces in that kind of situations :(

Comment: The best thing to do is keep it simple. You have a lot of verts there. Might be okay for producing renders, but for a game it's too dense. And the best way to keep it simple, in my opinion, is to box model around it and then SubSurf+Shrinkwrap that box model. Pay attention to the edge flow, but do keep it simple.

Comment: [I've made an example, from your screen shot](http://www.pasteall.org/pic/show.php?id=98804), of approximately the level of detail I would start with. Let SubSurf+Shrinkwrap fill in the rest. *Save As* before you apply modifiers - you will want to retain a copy of the original low-poly retopo mesh if you plan to [Reshape into a Multires Modifier](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38307/retopo-can-we-apply-shrink-wrap-to-multires-subdivisions).