# How to create a low poly model from a high poly model

Tags: modeling, texture-baking, baking, sculpting

I have a high poly model and I want to shift the resolution down.

I know about baking textures, but I was wondering wheter this is the best solution.

I don't need to capture all the details.

There is a function in zbrush that does this (you can choose how many percent of the polys that you want to keep), that shifts the resolution down but keeps most of the forms. It only tweeks it a little.

Comment: Could you please upload your .blend file to be able to help you?

Comment: I don't have my computer with me, but I'll send you one if I get to it. - The Idea is (if you have a cube and sibdivide it a thousand times, you still only have 6 sides (to which it can be simplyfied). however if i sculp in dynoscope mode, it'll always create more vertisies that it'd need

Comment: dyntopo not dynoscope (you could create a model yourself using a cube and modifiing it a bit) you'll see pretty fast that the model (even simple forms) of you sculpt enough, will become huge (for rendering and animation purposes)

Comment: Let me know and tag me when you upload the file.

Comment: Manual retopology if it's organic.

Comment: The Decimate Modifier is certainly one way, but if you want to create a lower poly version of your sculpt with nice topology [this may be of interest to you.](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38307/retopo-can-we-apply-shrink-wrap-to-multires-subdivisions)

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is to use the *Decimate* modifier. It allows you to control how much of your mesh your want to reduce.

The Decimate Modifier:

[image: Modifier decimate]