# How to apply sculpt mesh dimension to an original mesh?

Tags: sculpting

I have mesh that was sculpted and changed dimensions in process. Is it possible to apply sculpted mesh dimension on original low poli model.

Comment: Try the shrinkwrap modifier. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/deform/shrinkwrap.html#shrinkwrap-modifier

Comment: [This is related](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38307/retopo-can-we-apply-shrink-wrap-to-multires-subdivisions) and may be of interest to you.