# I would like to know how to use dyntopo with multi-density

Tags: mesh, sculpting

[image]

I think it is a big advantage of dyntopo to be able to sharply sculpting a part without subdividing the entire mesh.

However, when rubbed with a smooth brush, there is a tendency to leave traces near the boundaries of the different density topologies.

I have marked it with a red grease pencil on the attached photo.

How can I make this place a natural gradient?

Also, I would be grateful if you could give me the correct order or tips for multi-density work.

Comment: You can try using Subdivide Collapse method of dyntopo subdivision to subdivide and collapse geometry depending on the already subdivided density level. Note that patches and irregularities will appear every time when you have transition from low-subdivided to high-subdivided part because of triangles subdivisions in that area.

Comment: Yes, that's right.
However, there is a caution in usage for the method.
If we move the camera back and work a large-area on the mesh, the details we worked on first will be lost.
That's why we have to keep up with the workflow of sculpting small-area work after completing a large-area.

Comment: No matter how we do it, it's hard to have a smooth surface with only a dynamic topology.
We should avoid excessive detail work in the dynamic topology.
We have to move to multi-resolution after retopology.

Answer (score 1):

**1.** Avoid going too hi-poly if you don't have to. If you're planning to sculpt at this level of detail on your whole mesh, make sure your computer can keep up. And ask yourself if you really need that much geometry. In my opinion if your wireframe turns black in some spots, that's too many polygons.

[image: Mesh may be too dense]

You can change these settings to control how fine your sculpt will be. Personally, I find that Constant Detail is easier to manage than Relative Detail.

[image: Dyntop - Constant Detail]

**2.** The Smooth operation can help.

Back to basics, just press <kbd>W</kbd> in Edit mode and choose Smooth from the Specials Menu. If you Grow Selection (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>+</kbd>) and repeat, you can smooth over more area in steps.

**3.** You can always retopo (and usually should retopo after Dyntopo).

Personally, I like to do a [Multires retopo](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38307/retopo-can-we-apply-shrink-wrap-to-multires-subdivisions) to preserve the high level of detail but also be able to still manage the mesh.