# Losing detail when retopologizing

Tags: mesh, vertices, edges, sculpting

After the retopo is done a lot of detial is lost and if I use subsurf or multires and increase it it over 2 times it has double the amount of faces than the high res mesh and still not all the detail is back...any idea?

Comment: Related post - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38307/retopo-can-we-apply-shrink-wrap-to-multires-subdivisions  Related video - https://www.blendernation.com/2017/04/06/saving-lost-sculpted-details/

Answer (score 1):

Use the shrinkwrap-modifier in combination with a subsurf- or multires-modifier.
Make sure that the shrinkwrap is stacked lower than the subsurf- or multires-modifier to gain detail.

When using the multires-modifier, you can apply the shrinkwrap-modifier and the gained detail will be 'absorbed' by the multires. You can then enter sculpt mode to add and or smooth the desired detail while keeping your relatively low poly retopologized mesh.