# Multires subdivide causes distortion, what can cause this?

Tags: multiresolution

> Subdiv1

[image]

> Subdiv2

[image]

> Subdiv3

[image]

- Already tried fixing normals and merging duplicate vertices. Any idea
  why else this might happen?

Comment: Try to click Apply Base in modifier's settings. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/115661/2-issues-with-multires-modifier?rq=1

Comment: Here's how it worked for me. I clicked on apply base while in subdiv3, then deleted the multiresolution modifier and then re-applied it. On subdiv3 it worked.