# Shrinkwrap doing weird topology

Tags: modeling, topology

so Im trying to do a retopo of a model and Im having a problem.

I have a sculpted model, and now im trying to retopo this one with Shrinkwrap. First I have a mirror modifier and then a subdivision surface one, the last one is the Shrinkwrap.

My problem its that it makes weird things in the topology and i dont know what can be the problem.

This topology error happens as the same way in other parts of the model.

[image][image]

[image]

Comment: What is the modifiers stack and options for the shrinkwrap?

Comment: @lemon edited the question with this information. The orden is mirror, subdivision surface and shrinkwrap

Comment: Give a try to 'project' (but that's dependent on how surfaces overlap or not)

Comment: Topology is the wrong word here.  The shrinkwrap is preseverving your topo.  What you don't like is the positions of the vertices.  The vertices are behaving predictably-- they're shrinkwrapping to the nearest surface point, although it's not clear whether you're running your subdiv before or after the SW, and yes, it matters.  You might find it useful to occasionally duplicate and apply your SW modifier and then reposition verts as needed.

Answer (score 0):

My personal preference is to use vertex snapping, not shrink-wrapping, as a form of retopology to avoid this kind of problem.

Often excessive subsurface and/or complex topology can lead to this problem. Keep in mind that the shrink-wrap modifier uses the normal of each of the faces of the  mesh to calculate the deformation, not necessarily its proximity to the original one. Make sure it makes sense looking at it without shrink-wrapping it.

Other possibilities include that your normals are not consistent or the shrink-wrapped mesh is not completely outside the object to be retopologized. But as previously said, just look at the mesh with the modifier turned off and adjust to make it as clear as possible what you want to do.

I would take a youtube tutorial on shrink-wrap retopology so you understand the concept completely before proceeding.

Comment: I disagree, I think that shrink wrapping can save you a massive amount of time while retopologizing, and can give good topology for things like legs and arms.

Comment: @Millard To each their own preference, but I agree with you. And if you retopo [using a copy of your base mesh](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38307/retopo-can-we-apply-shrink-wrap-to-multires-subdivisions) it's much easier than rebuilding from scratch.